# How to extract the last year (YYYY) from a YYYY-YY format column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, datetime, apply

I am trying to extract the last year (YY) of a fiscal date string in the format of YYYY-YY. e.g The last year of this '1999-00' would be 2000.

Current code seems to cover most cases other than this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


test_df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Season':['1996-97', '1997-98', '1998-99', 
'1999-00', '2000-01', '2001-02',
'2002-03','2003-04','2004-05', 
'2005-06','2006-07','2007-08', 
'2008-09', '2009-10', '2010-11', '2011-12'],
'Height':np.random.randint(20, size=16), 
'Weight':np.random.randint(40, size=16)})
```

I need a logic to include a case where if it is the end of the century then my apply method should add to the first two digits, I believe this is the only case I am missing.

Current code is as follows:

```
test_df['Season'] = test_df['Season'].apply(lambda x: x[0:2] + x[5:7])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work too:

```
pd.to_numeric(test_df['Season'].str.split('-').str[0]) + 1
```

Output:

```
0     1997
1     1998
2     1999
3     2000
4     2001
5     2002
6     2003
7     2004
8     2005
9     2006
10    2007
11    2008
12    2009
13    2010
14    2011
15    2012
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to extract the first four digits

```py
df['Season'] = df['Season'].str.extract('^(\d{4})').astype(int).add(1)
```

```
    Season  Height  Weight
0     1997       4      22
1     1998      18       4
2     1999      19      27
3     2000       7      10
4     2001      19       9
5     2002      18      31
6     2003      19       9
7     2004      18      29
8     2005      13      17
9     2006      13      30
10    2007       5      14
11    2008      15       3
12    2009      13      10
13    2010      15       8
14    2011       0      23
15    2012       2      38
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go! Use the following function instead of the lambda:

```
def get_season(string):
    century = int(string[:2])
    preyear = int(string[2:4])
    postyear = int(string[5:7])
    if postyear < preyear:
        century += 1
    # zfill is so that "1" becomes "01"
    return str(century).zfill(2) + str(postyear).zfill(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the [fiscalyear](https://pypi.org/project/fiscalyear/) module.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import fiscalyear as fy

...

test_df['Season'] = test_df['Season'].apply(lambda x : fy.FiscalYear(int(x[0:4]) + 1).fiscal_year)
print(test_df)
```

Comment: Thank you, I like this answer did not know there was a fiscalyear module, this is really helpful!