# Python / pandas - Can i make it understand a YYYY-YY string as a period/range/interval of time?

Tags: python, pandas, date

So I'm trying to work with NBA data and all Seasons are like "1999-00". I wanna be able to extract more detailed data from it in some point of my project, but for that python has gotta recognize it as as a date of some kind. It seems that the format YYYY-YY does not exist (something like "%Y-%y").
I have read this [How to extract the last year (YYYY) from a YYYY-YY format column in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71879050/how-to-extract-the-last-year-yyyy-from-a-yyyy-yy-format-column-in-pandas) trying to get some insight, but it's not helpful for my purposes. In the future i want to be able to ask something like "did Jokic break any records from 2016 to 2020?", or even "who were the best 3-point shooter from 1999 all-star break to the 2001 playoffs?". Is there a way to operate with the strings i got from the database as a date format of some sort, or i will have to keep slicing, splitting, and navigating strings to do that?

I will use the same dataset the guy from the post i mentioned for testing the conversion and getting insights from you guys.

Thank you!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

test_df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Season':['1996-97', '1997-98', '1998-99', 
'1999-00', '2000-01', '2001-02',
'2002-03','2003-04','2004-05', 
'2005-06','2006-07','2007-08', 
'2008-09', '2009-10', '2010-11', '2011-12'],
'Height':np.random.randint(20, size=16), 
'Weight':np.random.randint(40, size=16)})
```

I tried investigating about Periods and date conversion functions in pandas, but no sucess so far (and it's been a while headbangin' over here!).

Comment: `1999-00` meaning 1999 to 1900? This will require a function to properly expand, or you could just collapse it as "1999" meaning "1999 to 2000 season" implicitly.

Comment: no @tadman, 1999 to 2000. Seasons in the NBA starts at october from one year and ends in June the next year. So the start isn't on Jan, neither the end in in Dec.

Comment: As a human I get that. I'm not sure Python would.

Comment: what is the meaning of last two digits of 1999-00

Comment: What day of the month does NBA season start?

Comment: So _"did Jokic break any records from 2016 to 2020?"_ would use data from 2016-17 or from 2015-16? Up to 2019-20 or 2020-21?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a [`Period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Period.html) (a special object with a useful behavior), use [`pandas.PeriodIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.PeriodIndex.html) to convert:

```
test_df['period'] = pd.PeriodIndex(test_df['Season'].str[:4], freq='A')
```

*NB. by default the yearly periods are anchored to the end of December, if your seasons have a different anchor, change the frequency. For example if the Season starts on the 1st of September:*

```
test_df['period'] = pd.PeriodIndex(test_df['Season'].str[:4], freq='A-AUG')
```

Output:

```
     Season  Height  Weight period
0   1996-97       2       3   1996
1   1997-98       3      11   1997
2   1998-99       2      22   1998
3   1999-00      11      13   1999
4   2000-01      13      11   2000
5   2001-02      16      16   2001
6   2002-03       8      24   2002
7   2003-04       8      29   2003
8   2004-05      19      21   2004
9   2005-06       8      25   2005
10  2006-07       2      16   2006
11  2007-08       3      19   2007
12  2008-09      12      33   2008
13  2009-10      14      32   2009
14  2010-11       0      36   2010
15  2011-12       4       6   2011
```

Comment: I works, thou problems seems to escalate quickly when dealing with "broken" calendars. First if I try to use "AS-APR", for eg., it doesn't work. How do i set the period anchored in the start date? And then, what i figured I really need is to get a day-to-day freq, but only from the first year in YYYY-YY october 1 to the next year (the -YY part) june 30, and that would be my year (without anything from July to September). Is it possible ?

Comment: @felipedmc what you really want to achieve is unclear, as questions should be limited to a single topic and this question was about the conversion, I'd recommend opening a new follow-up question with what you want to do after (aggregation, etc.)